# Javascript: how to move a context object in relation with its rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector, rotation

I want to make game using html canvas. My objective is to move a rectangle up and down, and it will rotate when I press left and right. Think like a car, cars only go forward and backwards but they don't go left and right, they rotate.
 The only problem is my rectangle rotates but it doesn't move in relation with its rotation, it only moves up and down no matter where it is facing.

```
this.Draw = function() {    //this goes inside constructor
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.fillRect( -1* this.width/2 , -1* this.height/2, this.width, this.height); //center context to get a center rotation
    ctx.restore();   };
```

I could not figure it out how to move the rectangle forward, so it just moves up and down.
  For my rectangle movement I used a list with the 4 inputs that I have, and then when they are true, they'll move. Here:

```
this.inputWASD = [false,false,false,false]; //this goes inside constructor
//input for ---->[ W  ,  A  ,   S  ,   D ]  <--------- 

switch(keyDown.key){
    case 87: //w
        rect1.inputWASD[0] = true;
        break;
    case 83:  //s
        rect1.inputWASD[2] = true;
        break;
    case 65:  //a
        rect1.inputWASD[1] = true;
        break;
    case 68:  //d
        rect1.inputWASD[3] = true;
        break;                     };

switch(keyUp.keyCode){
    case 87:
        rect1.inputWASD[0] = false;
        break;
    case 83:
        rect1.inputWASD[2] = false;
        break;
    case 65:
        rect1.inputWASD[1] = false;
        break;
    case 68:
        rect1.inputWASD[3] = false;
        break;     };


funtion Update() {
        if(this.inputWASD[0] == true){this.y-= velocity}    //UP and DOWN
        else if(this.inputWASD[2] == true){this.y+= velocity};

        if(this.inputWASD[1] == true){this.angle -= angleMovement}  //Rotate RIGHT and LEFT
        else if(this.inputWASD[3] == true) {this.angle += angleMovement};
```

If you don't know an answer but you know about a library that I can use to move a context object based on its rotation, please tell me.

Comment: You need to calculate the vector represented by the given angle and move the rectangle along that vector (rather than the original vertical vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to express the velocity in terms of polar coordinates. That means instead of storing and X and Y velocity you store an angle and a speed. Then in your update function you convert these into X and Y velocities to update the position. You can convert from polar to cartesian coordinates using trigonometry:

[image: x = r * cos(phi)]
[image: y = r * sin(phi)]

So in your code you would do something like this:

```
// In the Constructor
this.angle = 0;
this.speed = 0;

// ... //

function Update()
{
    this.speed = 0; // Do this if you want the rectangle to have no momentum

    // Input handling
    if(this.inputWASD[0]) this.speed += acceleration;
    if(this.inputWASD[2]) this.speed -= acceleration;

    if(this.inputWASD[1]) this.angle -= angleMovement;
    if(this.inputWASD[3]) this.angle += angleMovement;

    // Position update
    this.x += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.y += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
}
```

*Note:* I renamed `velocity` to `acceleration` to be more consistent with Physics terminology. Also I reset the speed to 0 on every tick so the rectangle has no momentum. If you want more realism you could remove that line and instead just decrease the velocity by a little bit (say 10% or so) on each update to simulate friction.

Comment: Good, the rectangle now moves to a specific direction, but not where it is facing, when I press "left" or "right" it moves to a random direction. Also when I put  `this.speed = 0;` in Update() my rectangle doesn't move.

Comment: The trigonometric convention is that the angle 0 is aligned to the positive X axis (to the right). You probably assume that the negative Y axis (upwards) is the direction your rectangle is facing. Probably the easiest fix is to draw the rectangle so that it's facing to the right and then initialize it with `this.angle = -90`.

Are you sure it is moving in a _random_ direction when you press `a` or `d`? That seems very unlikely. Maybe you left in some of your original updating code which changes `this.x` and `this.y` based on keyboard input.

Comment: As for the `speed` issue the order is important. You must set the speed to 0, then run my input-handling code which will may set the speed to `+acceleration` or `-acceleration`, and then update the position based on the speed. If you set the `speed` to 0 _after_ input handling but _before_ position update then pressing keys will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, It's almost there. My rectangle doesn't move in a random direction, but when pressing `a` or  `d` the angle rotation isn't synchronized. When I press `D` and turn 180 degrees, I'm supposed to move in the opposite direction, but instead it  the movement turns more than 180 degrees. I have the position updated like this `this.x += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);` and `this.y += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle)`. I was playing with that but I couldn't get it right

Comment: Note that `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` expect angles in radians just like `context.rotate()` does. So you should either express all your angles in radians or convert from degrees to radians with `this.angle * Math.PI / 180` each time.

Comment: Thanks very much, It worked!!!. I had to convert the parameters of Math.sin() and Math.cos in radials. I can finally start my game.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Using polar coordinates was the key. However, I did not get car-like behavior with your code. The rotation caused a "jump" rather than a smooth rotation and translation of the vector.

The only thing I needed to get the desired behavior was to add the existing Cartesian coordinates to the polar ones.